# How to get symbol info in binance socket manager api?

Tags: api, python-3.7, symbols, binance, binance-api-client

I am actually developing a binance api bot and I am trying to get the symbol info for the following currency pairs:

BTCAUD

BTCEUR

BTCGBP

And I tried following code to do it:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
from binance.enums import *
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException, BinanceOrderException
from twisted.internet import reactor
import os
import pandas as pd

from time import sleep

api_key='your api key'
api_secret='your secret key'
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)



#One:
btc_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTC_AUD")
# print full output (dictionary)
print(btc_price)


#Two:
btc_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCAUD")
# print full output (dictionary)
print(btc_price)

#Three:
btc_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTC_AUDT")
# print full output (dictionary)
print(btc_price)

#Four:    
btc_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCAUDT")
# print full output (dictionary)
print(btc_price)
```

But I am unable to get the ticker and info of these currency pairs and getting this error on above all four methods.

```
OUTPUT:
    raise BinanceAPIException(self.response)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1121): Invalid symbol.
```

Would anyone like to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself what was wrong, actually binance test api only has BTCUSDT and ETHUSDT for testing purpose, so I changed my test api and secret key with the original ones and checked it this way:

```
btc_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCAUD")
print(btc_price)

OUTPUT:

{'symbol': 'BTCAUD', 'price': '51341.55000000'}
```

It worked without any error.